# what's wrong here ? in solving $y'+2y=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was dealing with Ordinary differential equation, $y'+2y=1$
In my book it is solved using seperable variable form,
$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}y'&=1-2y\\\frac{dy}{dx}&=1-2y\\\frac{dy}{1-2y}&=dx\\\int \frac{dy}{1-2y}&=\int dx\\\frac{\log(1-2y)}{-2}&=x+c\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

But what I did,

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}y'&=1-2y\\\int y'dx&=\int 1-2ydx\\y&=x-2yx\\y+2xy&=x+c\\y(1+2x)&=x+c\\y&=\frac{x+c}{1+2x}\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

So I want to know, my way is also correct no? or where I am wrong..?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi there! The Mistake you are doing is that variable $y$ is a function of $x$, and so you cannot just integrate the RHS, while just treating $y$ as a constant. Its $y(x)$ not some constant.

Comment: The book's method omits the constant solution $y = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, $\int 1-2y \mathrm dx\ne x-2yx$. That's because $y$ isn't independent of $x$,but a function that has something to do with $x$. Take this for an example: suppose $y=x^2$ ,then $\int y\mathrm dx=\frac13 x^3$ but not $x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

As a check of the methods consider the problem a different way. First note that the equation is of first order giving rise to exponential or powers solutions. In this particular case the equation is of the type $y^{'} + a \, y = b$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. To make the equation easier note that the right-hand side is equal to a constant which suggests making the transformation $y = f + c$ where $c$ is a constant. This gives
$$ y^{'} + a \, y = f^{'} + a \, f + a \, c = b.$$
Let $c = \dfrac{b}{a}$ to reduce the equation to $f^{'} + a \, f = 0$. This can easily be shown to have the solution $f = c_{0} \, e^{-a \, x}$ such that $y = c_{0} \, e^{-a \, x} + \dfrac{b}{a}$.

Now, by separation of variable integration:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} + a \, y &= b \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= b - a \, y \\
\frac{dy}{b - a \, y} &= dx \\
- \frac{1}{a} \, \ln(b - a \, y) &= x + c_{1} \\
\ln(b - a \, y) &= - a \, x - a \, c_{1} \\
b - a \, y &= e^{- a \, c_{1}} \, e^{- a \, x} \\
y &= - \frac{1}{a} \, e^{- a \, c_{1}} \, e^{-a \, x} + \frac{b}{a} = c_{0} \, e^{-a \, x} + \frac{b}{a}.
\end{align}
This gives the same solution previously stated.

Another method for this type of equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} + a \, y &= b \\
e^{a \, x} \, \frac{dy}{dx} + a \, e^{a \, x} \, y &= b \, e^{a \, x} \\
\frac{d}{dx} \, \left( e^{a \, x} \, y \right) &= b \, e^{a \, x} \\
e^{a \, x} \, y &= \frac{b}{a} \, e^{a \, x} + c_{0} \\
y &= c_{0} \, e^{-a \, x} + \frac{b}{a}.
\end{align}